# Type 'string' is not assignable to type string literal when wrapped in Observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Given:

```
interface Abc {
  abcmethod: 'one' | 'two';
}
```

this line will cause error

```
const obj: Observable<Abc> = of({ abcmethod: 'one' });
```

where

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

Error is:

```
TS2322: 
Type 'Observable<{ abcmethod: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Abc>'.   
Type '{ abcmethod: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Abc'.     
Types of property 'abcmethod' are incompatible.       
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"one" | "two"'.
```

while without Observable it is OK

```
const obj: Abc = { abcmethod: 'one' };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix is to manually cast the object literal

```
const obj: Observable<Abc> = of({ abcmethod: 'one' } as Abc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the type bounds for the property value to `'one' | 'two'`, otherwise TypeScript assumes that the value has the `string` type, which isn`t compatible with your type. The correct solution would be:

```
const obj: Observable<Abc> = of({ abcmethod: (<'one' | 'two'> 'one') });
```

Comment: I like my solution with "as Abc" more, because this was simplified example of the problem but in my project, the object is much bigger and the problems occurs on several properties. And it is much cleaner to use "as Abc" at the end rather then define bounds for each property. But thank you anyway for another solution, it teaches me some new stuff :)